# AVQueuePlayer play/pause methods not updating UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, avplayerlayer, uiviewrepresentable, avplayerlooper

I have a looping video player that should play or pause based on a given `isPlaying` property. I initially created a looping video player (similar implementation to [this example](https://schwiftyui.com/swiftui/playing-videos-on-a-loop-in-swiftui/)) -- now I want the ability to pause it.

The UI initializes the video in the correct playing/paused state, but the UI doesn't update when `isPlaying` changes unless the view is unmounted and re-rendered.

I used `print` to confirm that `isPlaying` is the correct value and `updateUIView` invokes `play` or `pause`.

I'm wondering why the UI doesn't show the updated playing/paused of the video.

`isPlaying` is passed into the `LoopingVideoPlayer` like so

```
...
var body: some View {
    LoopingVideoPlayer(
      fileUrl: localUrl,
      resizeMode: .resizeAspectFill, 
      isPlaying: isPlaying)
}
...
```

My code for the looping video player:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

struct LoopingVideoPlayer: UIViewRepresentable {
    var fileUrl: URL
    var resizeMode: AVLayerVideoGravity
    var isPlaying: Bool = true

    private var loopingPlayerUIView: LoopingPlayerUIView

    init(fileUrl: URL, resizeMode: AVLayerVideoGravity, isPlaying: Bool = true) {
        self.fileUrl = fileUrl
        self.resizeMode = resizeMode
        self.isPlaying = isPlaying
        self.loopingPlayerUIView = LoopingPlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LoopingVideoPlayer>) {
        print("updateUIView called while isPlaying == \(isPlaying)")
        if isPlaying {
            loopingPlayerUIView.play()
        } else {
            loopingPlayerUIView.pause()
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        print("makeUIView called")
        loopingPlayerUIView.initPlayer(fileUrl: fileUrl, resizeMode: resizeMode)
        return loopingPlayerUIView
    }
}

class LoopingPlayerUIView: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private let queuePlayer = AVQueuePlayer()
    private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        playerLayer.player = queuePlayer
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }

    func initPlayer(fileUrl: URL, resizeMode: AVLayerVideoGravity) {
        print("initPlayer method invoked")
        let avAsset = AVAsset(url: fileUrl)
        let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)

        playerLayer.videoGravity = resizeMode
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: queuePlayer, templateItem: avPlayerItem)
    }

    func play() {
        print("play method invoked")
        print("playerLayer reference matches queuePlayer: \(queuePlayer === playerLayer.player)")
        queuePlayer.play()
    }

    func pause() {
        print("pause method invoked")
        print("playerLayer reference matches queuePlayer: \(queuePlayer === playerLayer.player)")
        queuePlayer.pause()
    }
}
```

Comment: You never set `isPlaying` to anything. You need to store the state in a parent and update it when the player starts/stops.

Comment: @jnpdx `isPlaying` is passed into the component. I updated the question to clarify how it is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the `isPlaying` value you'll need to use a [Binding](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding) variable. Currently when you pass true or false to your `LoopingVideoPlayer` representable you're creating a copy of the value that's being initialized. That means when you update your variable, it won't update `LoopingVideoPlayer.` However, a Binding creates a single source of truth.

The new code should look something like this:

```
struct LoopingVideoPlayer: UIViewRepresentable {
    var fileUrl: URL
    var resizeMode: AVLayerVideoGravity
    @Binding var isPlaying: Bool

    private var loopingPlayerUIView: LoopingPlayerUIView

    init(fileUrl: URL, resizeMode: AVLayerVideoGravity, isPlaying: Binding<Bool>) {
        self.fileUrl = fileUrl
        self.resizeMode = resizeMode
        self._isPlaying = isPlaying
        self.loopingPlayerUIView = LoopingPlayerUIView(frame: .zero)
    }

...
```

Then, in your parent view, the `isPlaying` variable should be a [State](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state) value as shown below:

```
...
@State var isPlaying: Bool = true

var body: some View {
  LoopingVideoPlayer(
    fileUrl: localUrl,
    resizeMode: .resizeAspectFill, 
    isPlaying: $isPlaying)
  }
...
```

I'd recommend reading up more on the relationship between State and Binding in SwiftUI [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper).

Comment: Aha! It looks like this is working. Now I see. Thank you very much!